# Explanation is needed at the end of Corpse Party - Tortured Souls OVA

Tags: corpse-party

I can't figure out what's going on at the end of episode 4 of the OVA. When Satoshi, Naomi and Ayumi finally preparing the ritual to go back to their own world, Satoshi told Naomi that he knows she took other person's paper scrap. Then, he gave her his paper scrap because he had Yuka's (his sister) one.

[image]

And then, at the final scene, they made it without Satoshi. What's wrong here? If they can't use other person's paper scrap, then why Naomi still alive? Wait, I guess they **can** use other person's paper scrap but **can't** use deceased one (*like Satoshi use his dead sister's one*)? If so, does Satoshi purposely sacrifice himself to let Naomi escape? It's confusing though, well, I watched the OVA but didn't played the game before.

[image]

Comment: That is not his sister's scrap, that is a scrap he found in another student's wallet, a student that was not a part of their ritual. I think it was in episode 2 or 4. Therefore, he was not using a scrap from their ritual, so he could not come back.

Comment: Coinciding with what Corpse Party Obsessor said, we don't actually know Satoshi is dead. If that school was still open then her would appear in one of the classrooms and might have even the slightest chance of surviving. It's a really low chance that's probably less then 50% but it keeps me from feeling sad over his death.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found a screenshot of the other student's ID.

[image]

Satoshi was using [Yuuya](http://corpseparty.wikia.com/wiki/Yuuya_Kizami)'s scrap, not his sister's; this resulted in his death on trying to return to his world. This is due to Yuuya not being a part of the ritual that Class 2-9 held, so his scrap could not bring Satoshi back.

Comment: But Satoshi said "Yuka" instead of "Yuuya", or did I missed something?

Comment: He lied, that is what you missed. If you did not get why they showed Yuuya's ID in the final scene, that means you did not notice that Satoshi lied.

Answer (score 2):

Recently finished this and after thinking about it for a while, I think Satoshi lied about the paper being his sister's.

If you go back and check, his sister didn't even participate in the ritual. And it was pretty weird that Satoshi gave Naomi his own paper instead of just giving her the extra charm. So the only explanation that makes sense is that Satoshi lied in order to bring Naomi Nakashima back safely while knowingly putting himself in jeopardy.

Satoshi gave Naomi his own charm to bring her back safely but maybe it wasn't such a selfless motive. He knew he couldn't live on in the real world again with the memory of his tortured little sister dying in his arms after stupidly leaving her behind alone with the girl with the red dress. We all saw the effect all of these memories had with Naomi, after she survived, she basically went insane.

(Note: In the Corpse Party game it's revealed that anyone that dies in the elementary school, memories of them are completely wiped out in the real world having them be completely forgotten by their loved ones)

Also worthy of noting, the ending when Naomi's mom is talking to her doctor about how Naomi keeps talking about "her friend" and how "she" doesn't exist brings us back to the scene of Naomi killing her best friend (Seiko Shinohara) while seemingly possessed.  For Naomi, being one of the only survivors in her group of friends, and not to mention killing and watching her her best friend die drove her to insanity.

Answer (score 0):

They can actually use someone else's scrap, as long as that person came to the school when they did. Satoshi gave Naomi his scrap and said he had Yuka's. Naomi lived because Satoshi came to the school with her. Satoshi, however, lied and sacrificed himself so Naomi could live. Satoshi actually used Yuuya's scrap. That is why at the end it showed his ID.

Comment: This is the same thing that Astral Sea's answer says. If you have the same answer as one that's already posted, please don't post it again; upvote the one that's already posted. If you think that the other answer is missing an important detail, you can suggest an edit to add it.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty much this guys that he used was the guy who killed Yuka named Kizami Yuuya, so Satoshi was sent to Kiazami's school but since he was holding hands with Naomi and Ayumi they were sent to their school with his arms and the rest of Satoshi was sent to I think it was called Byakuden or something. He then died of blood loss.

Comment: Do you have any proof that this happened?